# Drupal Installation Default Page not loading css

Tags: sqlite, drupal, drupal-8

I recently installed Drupal on Windows Server I had no errors on installation. There was a warning for OPCaching. I also don't think it should affect it but I used SQLite.

After installation the default page loaded with no CSS. Does anyone know why this happened or how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: From your browser open developer console (usually F12 key) go to "network" tab and reload the page. Check if CSS files are requested at all and if so what was the response from server. Could be that files have wrong access permissions...

Comment: @MilanG I ran the test and it showed 2 CSS Files but both were cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on another site, check the link attached.

> "You have enabled CSS compression through admin > Settings > Performance, so the compressed CSS file is creating at sites/default/files/CSS directory and the same file is loading.
>
> If you disable the CSS compression, you can see all the CSS files from the drupal core, contributed modules and theme.
>
> The CSS compressor will combine all the CSS files from the drupal core, contributed modules and themes and create a compressed file in sites/default/files/CSS.
>
> When you are developing, disable the CSS compression, when you deploy on a production server, enable CSS compression."

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Drupal-site-not-loading-CSS

Comment: Not sure that that answer fits your question. With CSS compression or not site should look the same. Anyway, would be good to place answer here, not just a link to it.

Comment: @MilanG I was a bit confused about why it wouldn't render as well, but as soon as I turned it off i saw the CSS files come through successfully in the network tab. Also I edited the solution to include the answer as well as the link.

Comment: It could be that your browser is making this problem by caching. Try it in different browsers..

Comment: BTW, if caching is on, you have to clear drupal cache after every CSS / HTML change, to see the difference.

Comment: @MilanG I am aware of the caching in browsers and I tried multiple receiving the same issue. The drupal caching though I was not aware of, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue with Drupal 9.
To resolve this I followed below steps:

1. Navigate to /admin/config/development/performance in your browser.
2. Under **BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION**, Uncheck **Aggregate CSS files** and **Aggregate JavaScript files** checkboxes.
3. Click on **Save configuration**.

This way the default/enabled theme will be loaded.
I Hope this will help !

Comment: This solved my problem, though I don't know if the failure of the aggregator leads to other problems.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Nginx like web-server or reverse proxy, you must disable some things (remove this block):

```
  location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
```

Now, the css and js will be work properly. Also Drupal can be created css/js in:

```
web/sites/default/files/css
web/sites/default/files/js
```

P/s: need to disable/enable **Aggregate CSS files** and **Aggregate JavaScript files** to Drupal re-create folder.

Answer (score -1):

In a clean installation, or even in case you cannot finish it due to the lack of CSS from the install.php page itself, check that wrong files/folders permissions are not preventing Drupal from reading folder "sites" content. Even a mistake you typed while editing the settings.php file could cause this.

If the issue persists once checked your permissions and cleared the cache in your browser (you can try on another browser to be sure), you can do this: rename your current settings.php file to settings.php.old, copy sites/default/default.settings.php to sites/default/settings.php and customize your database connection info. If it solves the issue, then check any differences between settings.php and settings.php.old and apply the proper corrections to your old settings file.

Answer (score -1):

I also had same problem while installing drupal on linux with apache server.
The site was not showing any css and js files.

solution that I found -
Go to your /etc/apache2/sites-available folder and add this configuration at the end of your file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sitename   #change site name
         ServerName site1.sitename.com #change the url
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after that restart apache server.Then you will be able to login on drupal site. Then goto configuration and clear cache you will get your missing css and javascript.